# sql server cache tuning

Tags: sql-server, caching

I have 2 questions about sql server cache, that help me tuning performance problem.

I read in an article that when I  query COUNT(*), all the pages of the table are loaded into the cache. Is it true?? Does it mean we load the same volume of data with 'select coun(*) ...' and 'select * ...' ??

When I query a 'select top ...' without an order by, the result of the query is loaded into the cache or all data are loaded into the cache and then the optimiser performs the top operation in the cache to select the desired data ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I m not sure what are you trying to optimize. But loading thing in cache doesnt sound right. Specially because cache isnt too big and content change between requests

Comment: my 1st question is that when I query a select count(*) what data is loaded into the cache?

Answer (score 0):

I can't help but wonder why you need to know, are you having specific performance problems or is this theoretical? As usual the answer is "it depends" - sql server will do all sorts of caching and optimisations depending on the query. It also not clear if you mean the in memory data cache or the query plan cache, but lets assume you mean how much data gets loaded into memory from disk and is thus "cached". The easiest way to answer this sort of thing is to run a query with some stats turned on

```
SET STATISTICS IO ON
```

Then run your queries and compare the results. The output will show "logical reads" and "physical reads". e.g.

```
Table 'ProductCostHistory'. Scan count 1, logical reads 5, physical 
reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, 
lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Each read is a page of data being loaded where physical is a read from disk and logical is a read from memory. Once the page is loaded from disk (physical) SQL Server will keep it in memory until it deems it suitable to evict it from the cache, so a second read of the same data would be considered logical. Using this you should be be able to measure your queries and determine for yourself which reads more data into/from the in memory cache. Note that if the server can use an index to answer your query it will, usually meaning far less data is read.

More info: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184361.aspx